# Delete tuples from postgress association table using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

i want to delete row from association table, which is secondary table to to the groups table.

```
class Groups(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'

    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), Sequence('groups_id_seq') , primary_key=True)
    group_name = db.Column(db.String())
    group_desc = db.Column(db.String())
    ngo_id = db.Column(db.String(), db.ForeignKey('ngo.ngo_id'))
    delete = db.Column(db.Boolean())

    group_donors = db.relationship('Donor', secondary=groups_donor_table, backref='groups')

    def __init__(self, group_name=None, group_desc=None, ngo_id=None, delete=True):
        self.group_name = group_name
        self.group_desc = group_desc
        self.ngo_id = ngo_id
        self.delete=delete
```

---

Association Table

```
groups_donor_table=db.Table('groups_donor_table',
                    db.Column('group_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('groups.group_id'), nullable=False),
                    db.Column('donor_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('donor.id'), nullable=False),
                    db.PrimaryKeyConstraint('group_id', 'donor_id')
                )
```

---

And the code to delete row

```
def delete_group_donors(group_id, json):
    donor_ids = json['delete_donors']
    group = db.session.query(Groups).filter_by(group_id=group_id).first()
    for donor_id in donor_ids:
     group_donor=db.session.query(groups_donor_table).filter_by(group_id=group_id, donor_id=donor_id).first()
        print group_donor
        group.group_donors.remove(group_donor)
        db.session.commit()
```

I am able to retrieve the data and add in the table, but cannot delete row.

error----

```
File "/home/mayur/Desktop/sahaj-backend/app.py", line 393, in update_group delete=delete_group_donors(group_id, details) File "/home/mayur/Desktop/sahaj-backend/app.py", line 432, in delete_group_donors group.group_donors.remove(group_donor) File "/home/mayur/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/o‌​rm/collections.py", line 1054, in remove fn(self, value) ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: are you having an error or nothing happens?

Comment: i have an error--------

 File "/home/mayur/Desktop/sahaj-backend/app.py", line 393, in update_group
    delete=delete_group_donors(group_id, details)
  File "/home/mayur/Desktop/sahaj-backend/app.py", line 432, in delete_group_donors
    group.group_donors.remove(group_donor)
  File "/home/mayur/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 1054, in remove
    fn(self, value)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: please, add your error message to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to remove is a `(group_id, donor_id)` tuple. There's no reason for you to need to manually operate on `groups_donor_table` at all because the relationship `group_donors` already handles it for you. What you need to remove from `group_donors` is not the `(group_id, donor_id)` tuple, but the `Donor` instance that has an `id` equal to `donor_id`.

A more straightforward way to do this is to simply build a new list of donors that should be kept:

```
donor_ids_set = set(donor_ids)
group.group_donors = [donor for donor in group.group_donors if donor.id not in donor_ids_set]
```

Comment: i don't want to delete all donor id's from the group donor table. i want to delete whichever id's come from front end.

Comment: @MayurPatil And that's exactly what I wrote.